# Web.xml Can a <servlet-name> be just a class?

Tags: jboss7.x, web.xml

I see lots of examples on the web of people doing this like..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/hello/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

However, that never works for me. I get an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name javax.ws.rs.core.Application
```

So what is the secret to be able to use a class name in a servlet-name directly ??

Answer (score 2):

I think @davideconsonni got it almost right:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: javax.ws.rs.core.Application extends Object its not a servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your servlet first:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```